# JPA inner join path not found and property not found

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a JPA Typed query join issue. When I use the following code

```
    SELECT cve from CubeValuesEntity cve inner join CubeConfigEntity cce
    on cve.cubeConfigId=cce.cubeConfigId
```

I get a QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! which I believe the fix to that error is the following

```
  SELECT cve from CubeValuesEntity cve inner join cve.CubeConfigEntity cce 
  on cve.cubeConfigId=cce.cubeConfigId
```

However I now get QueryException: could not resolve property: CubeConfigEntity
which makes no sense at all.

Here is the actual java code I used:

```
TypedQuery<CubeValuesEntity> query = em.createQuery(
   "SELECT cve from CubeValuesEntity cve inner join cve.CubeConfigEntity cce on cve.cubeConfigId=cce.cubeConfigId where " + "cce.cubeType = :cubeType 
   and cce.name = :name and cve.axisType = :axisType", CubeValuesEntity.class)
   .setParameter("cubeType", cubeType).setParameter("name", name).setParameter("axisType", axisType);

   return query.getResultList();
```

Here are my entities

```
    public class CubeValuesEntity extends AbstractDomainObject {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int cubeValueId;
private int cubeConfigId;
private String axisType;
private int axisNumber;
private String axisLabel;
private BigDecimal axisFactor;


public class CubeConfigEntity extends AbstractDomainObject {
private int cubeConfigId;
private String cubeType;
private String name;
private String yAxisName;
private Integer yAxisCubeSize;
private String xAxisName;
private Integer xAxisCubeSize;
private String reductionType;
private BigDecimal midLowRange;
private BigDecimal midHighRange;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a column `cv` in the `CubeValuesEntity` table? If so, please change the table alias  to `cve` (and `cce` for `CubeConfigEntity `) for clarity.

Comment: "cv inner join cv.CubeConfigEntity" is incorrect if you dont have a FIELD called CubeConfigEntity in "cv". But then you don't present your entities ...

Comment: there is no column called cv,  I will edit the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you're mixing JQL and SQL here.

Assuming you have a XToOne relation between CubeValuesEntity and CubeConfigEntity, a property named "cubeConfig":

- Forget the 'on' keyword - that's SQL, it's implied by the dotted expression and it's mapping
- "could not resolve property: CubeConfigEntity" seems logical since that's the entity name, not property

So, simply try this:

```
"SELECT cv from CubeValuesEntity cv inner join cv.cubeConfig cc where..."
```

br,
Jens

Comment: Correction : The ON keyword IS part of JPQL also, but its then for ADDING extra clauses to a join. To do a basic join you don't need it, as your example says

Comment: I changed the question to include the entities.  I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.

Comment: "Didn't work" as in you still get (another?) QueryException, or not the expected result?